# Change style of the div by mouse click and by second click change it back

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have prepared [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSAjV/2/) where I want to change background of the div "Child X" by mouse click and if it was clicked again on the already ***selected*** div then change the style back to original.

Right now there is a bug when the page just loaded, by the very first click on the child div nothing happens, only if I click second time then the color will be changed. Why ?

P.S. The other functionality should stay as it is, like clicking on the different div, the previous selected div should be unselected

```js
$(".childDiv").click(function () {
    const x = document.getElementsByClassName("childDiv");
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            const selectedEl = document.querySelector(".childDivSelected");
            if(selectedEl){
                selectedEl.classList.remove("childDivSelected");
            }
            this.classList.add("childDivSelected");
        }, false);
    }
})
```

```css
.parentDiv{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 width: 80px; 
  margin:5px;  
    display:relative;
}


.childDiv{
  border:1px solid blue;
 height: 50px;   
    margin:10px;
}

.childDivSelected{
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <div id="divParent1" class="parentDiv">
    Group 1
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divParent2" class="parentDiv">
    Group 2
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSAjV/2/)

Comment: IDs must be unique in a document. You have `id="child1"` and `id="child2"` multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a CSS class and then use [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to switch on/off the class for the selected element, to remove the class form the group elements and exclude the current clicked item you can use [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) and [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/):

```
$(this).parent().find('.childDiv').not(this).removeClass('selected');
```

Here is a working snippet or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mamounothman/830w2nt7/7/):

```js
$('.childDiv').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.childDiv').not(this).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.parentDiv{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 width: 80px; 
  margin:5px;  
    display:relative;
}


.childDiv{
  border:1px solid blue;
 height: 50px;   
    margin:10px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divParent1" class="parentDiv">
    Group 1
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divParent2" class="parentDiv">
    Group 2
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
```

in case you want to de-select all elements in the page, you can just remove `.parent().find()` and it will work for all elements:

```js
$('.childDiv').click(function(){
  $('.childDiv').not(this).removeClass('selected');
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.parentDiv{
 border:1px solid black;
 padding:10px;
 width: 80px; 
  margin:5px;  
    display:relative;
}


.childDiv{
  border:1px solid blue;
 height: 50px;   
    margin:10px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divParent1" class="parentDiv">
    Group 1
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divParent2" class="parentDiv">
    Group 2
    <div id="child1" class="childDiv">
        Child 1
    </div>
    <div id="child2" class="childDiv">
        Child 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that functionality doesnt work together with my already implemented functionality in my original post

Comment: @LDropl, I worked on it using jQuery, I though that you want the de-select functionality should work with the same group only not the whole `childDiv`, can you explain a bit more about this?